# Page N of M showing page 1 on every page

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have Page N of M Special field added in my page footer, but it shows "Page 1 of _" not only on page 1, but also on subsequent pages.

I checked all sections in my main report and subreports and I do not see any of them having Section Expert->Paging->Reset Page Number after set to TRUE.

I will appreciate any advise on what can be causing this issue and how to find it.

Comment: I am afraid you will have to share some details from your crystal report - please read the [ask] page for more tips on how to improve this question